# Unable to install box2d-py

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

I am trying to install this for reinforcement learning in python.

Writing `install box2d-py` in my command console on windows gives me back the error messages

```
ERROR: Failed building wheel for box2d-py
```

and

```
ERROR: Could not build wheels for box2d-py, which is required to
install pyproject.toml-based projects.
```

Comment: https://github.com/openai/spinningup/issues/32